# How to render amCharts Guide accurately on Line Chart?

Tags: amcharts

When the Line Chart with Guide is fully zoomed, Guide doesn't render in the middle. How do I correct position of Guide for given date?

Comment: For reference: http://jsfiddle.net/vghe08tw/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    "startOnAxis": true,
    "equalSpacing": true,
```

should solve this